# Classes as parameters

Tags: java, object-oriented, interfaces, inheritance

I would like to write a data structure implementation in Java that uses caches as a core part of its functionality, and I would like the user to be able to provide their own cache implementations that implement a particular cache interface so they can test performance using various strategies (like LRU, LFU, MRU, etc.).

What is the best way to allow a user to swap in their own cache in an instance of one of the data structures without giving them access to my codebase? Is there a way I can pass in a class that implements the cache interface as a parameter?

This structure will contain perhaps several caches arranged in different ways, so I would need more than one instance of a cache, and I would like to be able to create and destroy caches at runtime. Would passing a constructor to the cache as a Lambda function be a good solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A software design pattern to model runtime-dependent behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145803/a-software-design-pattern-to-model-runtime-dependent-behavior)

Comment: I'm not sure you can pass a class as a parameter, but I'm pretty confident you can pass an *instance* of a class that implements your desired interface.

Comment: You could try an event, that returns a (cached) value. Or a virtual method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the lines of your lambda idea, my suggestion would be to create a `CacheFactory` interface.

```
public class Whatever
{
  public Whatever(CacheFactory factory)
  {
    cache = factory.build(/* configuration options */);
  }
}
```

And you can do plenty of crazy things with that, if you like, such having your factory return singletons for certain caching types or strategies.

---

Alternatively, you could also use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)<sup>*</sup>

```
public class Whatever<C extends ICache> {
  private C cache;

  public Whatever() {
    cache = new CacheType();
  }
}
```

---

<sup>(*) You can do things similar to this in C#</sup>

Comment: Yes. Java supports generics (afortunately).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll opt for generics. However, just to know, why would the factory and generic strategies be preferred over a lambda?

Comment: @user129137 Any number of reasons: better testability, extensibility, state, more explicit contract / more semantic value, etc...

Comment: ... Lambdas, on the other hand, seem better to me for functions used *only in one place*, with an obvious purpose and/or when they more directly fulfill the requirements of the immediate context -- if that makes sense. For example, `Rockets.GetBrokenOnes()` might `return All.Where(r => r.isBroken)` or something -- the lambda is "elemental" in that context. It's not a separate, *nameable* responsibility... Silly example. Soft rule. Do whatever is sensible to you and your team.

Answer (score 6):

You could define a Cache interface which establishes a contract that you expect their implementation to abide by. Then allow them to then pass in their own implementation in the constructor (or setter method). i.e.

```
public class YourDataStructure {
    private final Cache cache;

    public YourDataStructure(Cache instanceOfTheirCacheImplementation) {
        cache = instanceOfTheirCacheImplementation;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to explain that I might want several instances of the cache in my structure, so passing in a single instance wouldn't suffice

Comment: @user129137 it could. You could make an aggregate cache.

Comment: @Zymus has a good solution. Effectively just include in the interface a method which adds a new cache. Alternatively, have the user provide a `CacheFactory` instead of a `Cache`, then you can make all the caches you desire.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor Hehe ... A `CacheFactory` you say. You mean like *my* answer? ... :)

Comment: @svidgen Yes exactly! When I wrote my answer, the question didn't include details about needing to create caches willy nilly.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor Yes. I do appear to have had the benefit of coming late to the game.